# What is the correct way to call named functions in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In Rails asset pipeline, what is the correct way to call named functions?

For example, calling a named function in the same file, as follows, appears to work perfectly.

```
#alerts.js.coffee
show_alert = (msg) ->
  alert(msg)

$(document).ajaxComplete (event, request) ->
  show_alert 'ajax completed'
```

but calling show_alert from another coffee file does not work

e.g. with [Jquery fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload),

```
#jquery_fileupload.js.coffee
jQuery ->
  $("#container").fileupload
    stop: (e, data) ->
      show_alert 'File upload stopped'
```

returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: show_alert is not defined`

No doubt a basic issue, but I would appreciate some pointers. I'm not a javascript/coffescript expert, and searching has revealed that "coffeescript does not support named functions" so I'm probably using the wrong terminology. What should I be referencing here?

Comment: `alert.js.coffee` must be loaded before `jquery_fileupload.js.coffee`. Are you doing that?

Comment: thanks @KumarAbinash, that makes sense. During deployment Rails compiles individual coffeescript files into a single JS file. Is there a way to call "named functions" that is not dependent on order?

Comment: ["Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })()`; This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the var keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident."](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope). You want `@show_alert = ...` or `window.show_alert = ...` to push it into the global namespace or use your own namespace. This is a duplicate but my search-Fu seems to be weak this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coffeescript does **function expression** rather than a **function definition**. So your coffeescript function should appear before your function execution code.

One way is to put your functions inside a object and execute them upon document load.

```
#alert.js.coffee
window.MyHelperFunctions =
  show_alert: (msg) ->
    alert msg


#jquery_fileupload.js.coffee
jQuery ->
  $("#container").fileupload
    stop: (e, data) ->
      MyHelperFunctions.show_alert 'File upload stopped'
```